# intermittent results using URLSession with Combine

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, combine

I have the following code running in a playground that supposed to print an array of 4 clues based on a random category ID. The category ID and the Correct URL used to get the clues are always printed correctly However, the clue results are printed intermittently sometimes its successful other times. Can anyone help me figure out why it sometimes does not print the array of clues yet the URL is correct?

```
import Foundation
import Combine

// MARK: - ClueElement
struct ClueElement: Codable {
  let id: Int
  let answer, question: String
  let value: Int
  let categoryID: Int
  let category: Category

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, answer, question, value
    case categoryID = “category_id”
    case category
  }
}


// MARK: - Category
struct Category: Codable {
  let id: Int
  let title: String
  let cluesCount: Int

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, title
    case cluesCount = “clues_count”
  }
}


enum HTTPError: LocalizedError {
  case statusCode
  case post
}



typealias Clue = [ClueElement]

var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

func loadData() {
  let url1 = URL(string: “http://www.jservice.io/api/random”)!
  cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url1)
    .map { $0.data }
    .decode(type: Clue.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .tryMap { category in
      guard let categoryID = category.first?.categoryID else { throw HTTPError.post}
      guard let cluesCount = category.first?.category.cluesCount else { throw HTTPError.post}
      print(“\(categoryID)“)
      return (categoryID,cluesCount)
  }
  .flatMap { (categoryID,cluesCount) in
    return getClues(for: categoryID, cluesCount: cluesCount)
  }
  .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in

  }) { clues in
    print(clues)
  }
}

func getClues(for id: Int, cluesCount: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Clue, Error> {
  let url = URL(string: “http://www.jservice.io/api/clues?category=\(id)&offset=\(cluesCount - 4)“)!
  print(url)
  return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map { $0.data }
    .decode(type: Clue.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

loadData()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a print statement in your `receiveCompletion:` closure and you will learn why your code doesn't print sometimes.

```
.sink(
    receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print(completion)
    },
    receiveValue: { clues in
        print(clues)
    }
)
```

I saw this when I did it:

```
failure(Swift.DecodingError.valueNotFound(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2), CodingKeys(stringValue: "value", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Int value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil)))
```